# ExecuteReader CommandText property has not been properly initialized

Tags: vb.net, executereader

First of all sorry if some of the code isn't right. I'm still new to using sql on vb.net

I have the following code:

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub btnLoad_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnLoad.Click
        Dim objConn As MySqlConnection
        Dim objDataset As New DataSet
        Dim objDataAdapter As MySqlDataAdapter
        Dim myCommand As MySqlCommand

        Dim sqlConn As String

        objConn = New MySqlConnection("server=localhost;userid=root;database=attendance_system")
        myCommand = objConn.CreateCommand

        objConn.Open()
        Dim objReader As MySqlDataReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader

        sqlConn = "SELECT student_name FROM profile"
        objDataAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter(sqlConn, objConn)
        objDataAdapter.Fill(objDataset, "profile")

        MsgBox("The Connection is Now 'OPEN'")

        objReader.Read()

        TextBox1.Text = objReader("student_name")

        objReader.Close()
        objConn.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

I am using MySQL connector via vb.net in phpmyadmin and have set a database with records.
The connection string is working, but my problem is when I try to click the button to load the data in the textbox, I keep getting:

> The CommandText property has not been properly initialized."

The error is on this line:

```
"Dim objReader As MySqlDataReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader"
```

I've tried a lot of fixes that I've found on this site and the others as well.

Comment: It is probably best to remove the line `Imports System.Data.SqlClient` if you are not also using MS SQL Server. Otherwise there is a chance you will get the wrong thing (unintended name resolution) somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

This is the problem:

```
Dim objReader As MySqlDataReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader

sqlConn = "SELECT student_name FROM profile"
```

You're declared the SQL *after* you've tried executing the query (and even then you don't set it as the SQL for the command). How would you expect that to work? Additionally, `sqlConn` is a very strange name for a variable declaring the *SQL* - I'd expect it to be a *connection*.

It looks like you're trying to mix too very different ways of fetching data:

- Reading directly from the reader
- Filling a `DataSet` with a data adapter

You shouldn't be mixing them like that. Work out which you *actually* want to do, take out all the code related to the other style, and then make sure you're doing everything in a sensible order.

Comment: Thank you for a _straight to the point_ reply. I'm really new with this stuff and I definitely need a hand. I'll be trying it again and see what I can come up based on your suggestion. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From [MySqlCommand Class](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/docs/Devart.Data.MySql~Devart.Data.MySql.MySqlCommand.html) and the example given as

```
Public Sub ReadMyData(myConnString As String)
  Dim mySelectQuery As String = "SELECT * FROM Test.Dept"
  Dim myConnection As New MySqlConnection(myConnString)
  Dim myCommand As New MySqlCommand(mySelectQuery, myConnection)
  myConnection.Open()
  Dim myReader As MySqlDataReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader()
  Try
    While myReader.Read()
      Console.WriteLine(myReader.GetInt32(0).ToString() + ", " _
        + myReader.GetString(1))
    End While
  Finally
      ' always call Close when done reading.
      myReader.Close()
      ' always call Close when done with connection.
      myConnection.Close()
  End Try
End Sub
```

Your command object is missing the select statement.

Comment: It would be simpler to use `Using` statements - I wonder whether that example was written from the first version of VB.NET which didn't have `Using`...

Comment: That seems fair, will have a look quick X-)